# How do I enter the Euro and the at sign on a MacBook?

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, macbook

I am using Xubuntu 16.04 exclusively on an old MacBook from 2007.

My keyboard is Portuguese. In `Settings/Keyboard/Layout` I defined the keyboard model as MacBook, `Change layout option` as Left-Alt and `Composer key` as Right-Alt. I tried also several 3rd level keys without any luck.
Normally in the Portuguese keyboard I will get the "at sign" symbol using Left-Alt 2.

Now the only way was to do `Ctrl+Shift+U+40` to get the @. I am aware that there are similar questions but with the exception of this answer none have worked.

```
$ setxkbmap -query -v 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules: evdev
model: pc105
layout: pt
variant: mac
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes: evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types: complete
compat: complete
symbols: pc+pt(mac)+inet(evdev)
geometry: pc(pc105)
rules: evdev
model: pc105
layout: pt
variant: mac
```

Comment: Please run the command `setxkbmap -query -v 10` in a terminal window and show us the output by editing your question.

Comment: Here is the output:  Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     pt
variant:    mac
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+pt(mac)+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     pt
variant:    mac

Comment: I added the output to the question for better formatting. Based on the info you provide, I miss a few things. Possibly it would behave more like what you want if you run this command: `setxkbmap -option "lv3:lalt_switch,lv3:ralt_alt,compose:ralt"`

Comment: Yes now is almost fine. I get @ with Alt+2. The only exception is with Alt+3: I get a £ instead of an Euro. A sign of times?

Comment: You access the € symbol via <Alt>+E with the keyboard layout you are using. Please also see the answer I posted.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it before. <Alt>+e gives €.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the XKB options I proposed in a comment persistent (i.e. preserved when rebooting), you can open the `/etc/default/keyboard` file for editing and change the line

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

to

```
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:lalt_switch,lv3:ralt_alt,compose:ralt"
```